# Setting/Returning value in a property of a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

While this may not be a WPF exclusive issue, I'm rather new to the technology so I'm not certain how to solve this. I need to set value to a property based on the status of the check box. Prior to work the property looks like this and is located in different project/class in the solution:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "MyElement_A")]
public bool MyElement_A { get; set; }
```

There is file MainWIndows.xaml where the control is created `<CheckBox Content="Check if Yes" Name="checkBox1"/>`

So I thought that perhaps something like this would work but I'm out of context and the `set` also has an error "must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial":

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "MyElement_A")]
public bool MyElement_A {
    get
    {
        return (bool)checkBox1.IsChecked.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

I know in "web" world you have to use `.FindControl`, I thought in WPF, state isn't an issue. What I'm asking is how do you get the value of the check box and assign it to the MyElement_A?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. Why isn't the check box bound to `MyElement_A`. Also, your setter shouldn't just `return` if you expect the backing field (which doesn't seem to exist) to update.

Comment: I need to set the `MyElement_A` to either false or true based on user's checking or unchecking the box.

Answer (score 3):

This is what binding is for.

You should have this:

```
<CheckBox Content="Check if Yes" IsChecked="{Binding MyElement_A }"/>
```

Of course, that will only work if the class containing `MyElement_A` is the `DataContext` for the view. Judging by your code, I would strongly reccommend looking into learning the MVVM pattern and how to use it with WPF. You will find that stuff like this becomes a *lot* easier.

Comment: Thank for the input. I was literally been given this rather simple app to make some changes and bug fixes, but it's in WPF and I know nothing of that. So I'll have to some OT to study up on this. I found nothing in the where the `"{Binding...` is used and there are plenty of other controls.

Comment: @Risho If you have any questions while learning MVVM, feel free to drop by the WPF chat room. It really is a lot easier to do stuff like this once you get the hang of it.